# why clip video cost so much time and cpu?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I use ffmpeg to clip video.And it uses 1/4 of video duration to clip video,and it takes high percent of CPU.I want to know is there any more advanced method to clip video which takes little time or cpu?

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is CPU intensive. Some broad, generic suggestions to your broad question:

- Add `-c copy` to enable [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. (However cuts must be made on keyframes.)
- If you can't stream copy the video then stream copy the audio (`-c:a copy`).
- Use a faster encoding preset if using libx264 or libx265.
- Use hardware accelerated encoding.
- Use an encoding service to do it for you.
- Don't use an ancient `ffmpeg`.